# Should I be able to delete comments from a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

I just made a comment to an answer (not mine). The user deleted their answer. This message was displayed just below their answer:

> deleted by owner 28 mins ago
>
> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

The funny thing is that I was able to delete my comment (probably edit it too?).

Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes. Why not? You are prevented from adding a *new* comment to a deleted question, but you can remove comments that you have already posted.

Comment: What @CodyGray said; also, I'm not sure you can *edit* comments on deleted posts. You might want to try [going to the formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), posting an answer then a comment, deleting the answer, then seeing if you can edit the comment.

Comment: @Andrew [did it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/127080#comment605556_127080) and yes, we can edit comments even when the post is deleted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Excellent; That's interesting. I'm not opposed to that at all, but didn't know it!

Comment: @Andrew now you know! Well, it's only for 5 minutes anyway so assuming most posts survive longer, not very relevant. :-)

Comment: @sha Ever since becoming an Evil Unicorn Overlord, I forget the limitations of you mere mortals sometimes. ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber [Can you get me in](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LlI6V.png)  .. like.. *quietly* ? :)

Comment: @AsheeshR Where did you get that screenie? I don't see the thing about it coming from the mobile app anywhere! I'm jealous!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Get me in, and I will tell you :P

Comment: @AndrewBarber On a slightly serious note, you probably need to find somebody else using the app, and hover on the timestamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deletion is not a preservation mechanic. It is a removal mechanic that we preserve for review but it is not in itself a means to preserve things in their last state. It is in fact a means for cleanup, and in that mind, allowing comment deletion is also helpful towards that goal.

We allow authors to delete their own comments in case they made mistakes, or they are alerted of the comment no longer being necessary, and a host of other very reasonable things. None of these particularly cease to apply once an answer has been deleted. Certainly, there's the potential for an author to delete a useful comment, but there's no reason that being on a deleted post, wherein to the majority of users the comment is *already* gone, it should be protected from deletion.

Comment: Sounds fair enough :)